# how to use thymeleaf th:xx to achieve the JSTL code <c:forEach begin="1" end="12" var="item">

Tags: thymeleaf

how to use thymeleaf th:xx to achieve the JSTL code :`<c:forEach begin="1" end="12" var="item"> </c:forEach>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<th:block th:each="item: ${#numbers.sequence(1, 12)}">

</th:block>
```